# Getting CS:GO player stats

Tags: steam

How could I use the Steam Web API to get a player's stats, such as "Total Kills" or "Total Wins". Some sites that use these features include http://csgo-stats.com and http://csgo-stats.net. I have tried using `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalStatsForGame/v0001/?format=xml&appid=730&count=1&name[0]=total_wins` with no success. Where is the documentation for such statistics?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong API end point for this. Utilize the [`GetUserStatsForGame`](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetUserStatsForGame_.28v0002.29) end point instead.

Your call will look like this:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=<<KEY>>&steamid=<<PROFILEID>>
```

You'll replace `<<KEY>>` with your API key and `<<PROFILEID>>` with the profile ID (not SteamID) of the user you are interested in. This value is the same one passed to you when you [sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674042/steam-api-authentication/18680478#18680478) via Valve's OpenID.

This will return a result similar to this:

```
{
    "playerstats": {
        "steamID": "7656-EDITED-OUT",
        "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
        "stats": [
            {
                "name": "total_kills",
                "value": 110527
            },
            {
                "name": "total_deaths",
                "value": 95930
            },
            {
                "name": "total_time_played",
                "value": 5784386
            },
            {
                "name": "total_planted_bombs",
                "value": 2726
            },
            {
                "name": "total_defused_bombs",
                "value": 594
            },
            {
                "name": "total_wins",
                "value": 26937
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

You can see that you need to iterate through the `['playerstats']['stats']` element and look at the `name` attribute of each to find the stats you are looking for.

Comment: does this work now? I dont think so... I am trying but it is giving me empty results

Comment: @Umair  Maybe You are trying to get "Your own" stats, i.e.  Your `steamid` parameter is the same that is linked to Your API `key`.
I had very similar problem today. It seems like You cannot do that with `GetUserStatsForGame`.  (Internal Server Error)