# How do I "call" something in java script

Tags: javascript, steam-web-api

Ok, so I am relatively new to the javascript scene, and I just had a few questions based off of this post here: [Getting CS:GO player stats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752856/getting-csgo-player-stats). In the answer, Andy says "Your call will look like this" then he inserts this link:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=<<KEY>>&steamid=<<PROFILEID>>
```

What is the call he talks about and how do I use this link? Thanks!

Comment: That's an API call, you will need to use AJAX or a framework like Angular (or Meteor, or Ember, list goes on) to that allows you to do HTTP requests. jQuery also comes with an $.ajax functionality out of the box.

Comment: The expectation is to send an HTTP request to the address (this can be done client-side with [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX), barring the [SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)), after replacing the `<<KEY>>` and `<<PROFILEID>>` with appropriate values.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a RESTful API[1] then you need to make a HTTP GET, POST, PUT, or PATCH request to that URI to retreive or alter the resource (the concept of a "resource" is abstract is REST).

In JavaScript you use AJAX, which is shorthand for the built-in `XMLHttpRequest` object which makes HTTP requests for you. Using libraries like jQuery can further simplify this for you:

```
var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log( this.responseText ); // got response, do processing here
});
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=<<KEY>>&steamid=<<PROFILEID>>");
xhr.send();
```

[1]The endpoint you posted is not strictly RESTful because the resource path itself contains a verb: `GetUserStatsForGame`, if it were fully RESTful then the URI should look like this: `/ISteamUserStats/Games/{gameId}/`, but I digress.