# Steam OpenID API

Tags: php, openid, steam

I want to make Steam login for my site. The only thing I want from Steam is to login, get his username and start a session for that user. I followed a tutorial on YouTube, did basically everything on that video but when I press sign in through Steam I get: example.com/(()%7D.
Code:

```
    <?php
   include "includes/apikey.php";
 include "includes/openid.php";

ob_start();

$OpenID = new LightOpenID("http://astral-gaming.com");

session_start();

?>
```

This is my header. Also, I put this php on the middle of the doc (because I want sign in to appear after all navbar elements:

```
<?php 

if(!$OpenID->mode) {

if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
 $OpenID->identity = "http://steamcommunity.com/openid";
 header("Location: ($OpenID->authUrl()}");
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['T2SteamAuth'])) {
 $login = "<li><a href =\"?login\"><img src=\"http://steamcommunity-        a.akamaihd.net/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_small.png\"/></a></li>";
 }
} elseif($OpenID->mode == "cancel"){

} else {

if(!isset($_SESSION['TF2SteamAuth'])) {
$_SESSION['TF2SteamAuth'] = $OpenID->validate() ? $OpenID->identity: null;
$_SESSION['TF2SteamID64'] =       str_replace("http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/", "",     $_SESSION['TF2SteamAuth']);

if($_SESSION['TF2SteamAuth'] !== null) {

$Steam64 = str_replace("http:// (ignore     space)steamcommunity.com/openid/id/", "", $_SESSION['TF2SteamAuth']);
$profile = file_get_contents("http:// (ignore space) api.steampowered.com/IsteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key={$api}&steamids=($Steam64)");
$buffer = fopen("cache/{$steam64}.json", "w+");
fwrite($buffer, $profile);
fclose($buffer);


}

header("Location: index.php");

}

}
if(isset($_SESSION['T2SteamAuth'])) {

$login = "<li><a href =\"?logout\">Steam LogOut</a></li>";
}

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {

unset($_SESSION['T2SteamAuth']);
unset($_SESSION['T2SteamAuth']);
header("Location: index.php");


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steam API Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674042/steam-api-authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad/mismatched bracketing/bracing everywhere in your code:

```
 header("Location: ($OpenID->authUrl()}");
                   ^-- this should probably be a {?
```