# OpenID2.0 doesn't work for steam

Tags: php, openid, steam

I wanted to add a login on my website (PHP), I used a [github](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication) repository

for this, but it uses OpenID 2.0, which doesnt work.. How to solve this? I am not the best in php etc. so I want some code..

Comment: All people fix my grammar, But dont answer?!!?!?!?

Comment: If you want to utilize Steam for logging in, look at my [answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674042/steam-api-authentication/18680478#18680478).