# Sign in through Steam with Java

Tags: java, jsf-2, openid, steam, steam-web-api

I want to use STEAM-LOGIN in my JSF2 web application. I found this in Steam Web API documentation:

"Steam can act as an OpenID provider. This allows your application to authenticate a user's SteamID without requiring them to enter their Steam username or password on your site (which would be a violation of the API Terms of Use.) Just download an OpenID library for your language and platform of choice and use http://steamcommunity.com/openid as the provider. The returned Claimed ID will contain the user's 64-bit SteamID. The Claimed ID format is: http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/"

Here are my questions:

- There are several OpenID libraries for Java, which one should I use?
- I have no idea how to implement redirection to Steam login page and back to my page

I found some examples for PHP but nothing for Java.

Comment: [This might answer the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18680478/4808244)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pac4j](http://www.pac4j.org/index.html). It has openid connect support.

They also have several implementations that they offer [here](http://www.pac4j.org/implementations.html).

You can see [here](https://github.com/pac4j/j2e-pac4j-demo) an example of pac4j's j2e implementation.