# Partialy visible PHP code in page, using OpenID

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I'm trying to get some info from steampowered.com, I have to use OpenID and there is my issue. I was following this post
[Steam API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674042/steam-api-authentication)

Even when I try to use examples I still get the same error. Sending pictures

Loaded page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzCFd.png)

Source code from that page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkKAZ.png)

My site is saved with .php extension and I am runnin WEMP (also tried WAMP - same error).

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Comment: It looks like the `->` is being detected as PHP end tag. This might have to do with php.ini, but I have never encountered anything like that. Why use any *AMP when you can download the official PHP, official Apache server, and make your own setup, so you wouldn't get any of this weird behavior.

Comment: When I uploaded the code to the web hosting server it works. There has to be something with my PHP...